# App doesn't rotate on iPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, simulator

I'm wanting to test out my app with the iPhone 5 resolution, so I'm using the simulator. My app has Portrait and 2 landscape orientations in Supported Device Orientations, and the viewControllers which allow rotation have `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` set to YES. Yet when I rotate the device in the simulator, it doesn't rotate as it does on the device. Right now i'm just using the standard iPhone 4 simulator.

Edit: This is the code I have for setting my VC.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self.window addSubview:self.navigationController.view];

self.loadingWood = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
[vc.view addSubview:self.loadingWood];
```

And then shortly after:

```
self.timeline = [[JTimelineViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:self.timeline]];
```

This is necessary for visuals when the app starts up.

EDIT 2:

I now have this working. The problem I now face is that despite one of my viewControllers stating this, it still rotates upon any rotation on the iPhone Simulator:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);

}
```

EDIT 3: My phone is running iOS5. The simulator is running iOS6. This is a possible reason. Removing Landscape Left and Landscape Right as supported orientations means no simulator rotation at all, but my iOS5 iPhone 4 continues to rotate as normal.

Comment: Does it rotate on the iPhone 4 simulator?

Comment: No. It rotates on the actual iPhone 4 that I have though.

Comment: Wow, interesting... Let me try this out! I'm really curious now... :D

Comment: Pretty good question. +1! Even though, I just created a new project in Xcode and ran the code in the iPhone simulator (both 4 and 5) and rotations work properly. Without code, it could be a bit tricky to debug.

Comment: Can you try replacing that setViewControllers: line with [self.navigationController pushViewcontroller:self.timeline animated:NO(or YES if you want animation)];

Comment: This worked, but check my edit above.

Comment: That code for shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is in your timeline vc or the main vc?

Comment: It's in timeline VC. The rotation doesn't happen when the main VC is on screen.

Comment: Just to make things clear, you want it to rotate or no?

Comment: I want it to rotate on the views where shouldRotate is set to YES.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're setting the root view controller, as in:

```
    self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
```

Comment: This worked, but now if it's on a viewController which allows rotating and is rotated into landscape, and then it goes back to a viewController which doesn't allow rotation into landscape, it shows the viewController in landscape. Any way to stop that from happening?

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with something similar in the past. What's going in is that only the main view controller of the application receives the rotation notifications and delegate calls. There are some exceptions, like the UINavigationController, that passes down those events to their current view controller.

So, for example, if your AppDelegate class loads a view controller and that view controller pushes a second view controller, that second view controller will not receive the rotation notifications.

I recommend you use a UINavigationController to push your UIViewControllers onto the display, since UINavigationController passes down the rotation delegate calls and notifications.

*EDIT*

In Xcode's preference, under the Download tab, you have the option of downloading previous simulators, iOS 5 and iOS 5.1. Download those and set your target iOS version to 5.0 (or 5.1) and select the correct simulator from the device list. See if you get the same problem as with the iOS 6 simulator. If you get that, than there's definitely a difference between iOS 5 and iOS 6's way of handling UINavs.

Also, using the difference between `setViewControllers` and `pushViewController` is that `pushViewController` adds the view controller as a child of the parent view controller, which makes it respond to the delegate calls, including rotation. Since iOS 5, every UIViewController now has a method called `addChildViewController` that gives that functionality to the `UIViewController` class.